# Why does std::is_copy_constructible not work as expected?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, type-traits

My compiler is VC++ 2013 RC.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    auto b = std::is_copy_constructible<A>::value;
    // Now b is TRUE! Rather than false.
}
```

Is this a BIG BUG of VC++ 2013 RC?

**Update:**

[ideone](http://ideone.com/wqgtoj) gives the corret result.

Comment: Unrelated comment... the main purpose of the `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` is to control the allocators used for objects stored inside containers (rather than only the data structure used for the container). It is a proposal from Bloomberg based on their [BSL](https://github.com/bloomberg/bsl), except that in BSL *all* allocators are *scoped*. Take a look at the available examples which you can run with the test allocator to see the purpose of the feature.

Comment: **EDIT** is there to **fix** or further explain an existing question, if you have a **new different** question, ask a different question. **How** is the question *is there a concise example of `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor`* relate to the edited *why does `std::is_copy_constructible` not work as expected*? This is **not** an edit, but a new completely different question

Comment: @David, Because I have reached the limit of questions in a month. So I cannot ask a new one but edit an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a bug in Visual C++ 2013. According to [**their website**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx), `=delete` and `=default` are to be implemented in the RTM version, so it's surprising that the RC does not properly evaluate it. You could check their [**bug database**](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) and file a new one if it hasn't been  mentioned before.

Comment: I've summitted a bug to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @xmllmx I hope it will get fixed in time!